# Creation of relationship with attribute in CoreData with iOS in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I would like to create a model with two entities **Orders** and **Products**. They are linked by a relationship '***Contain***' that has an attribute '***quantity***'. How can I represent that in CoreData ? (Do not send me the ray tutorial, or any tutorial on youtube, I think I have done every thing). It is very important the **relationship with attribute** and not something general. (I know that it is not a database, but it is a Conceptual data model/Conceptual Schema as it is named by "entities" and "relationship" so if there is relationships, there must be a way to have relationships with attribute).
[image]

**EDIT :** 
Am I doing the right thing by not adding id_order and id_product to the **Contain** entity ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CoreData, `Contain` would be another entity. It would have relationships to `Orders` and `Products` and a quantity attribute.

You cannot add attributes to a relationship in CoreData.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I believed, but I would like to be sure. It is the same way if I've done it under Sqlite directly by creating a table with Contain and a field quantity.

Comment: Am I doing the right thing by not adding id_order and id_product to the Contain entity ? (I edited my post).

Comment: CoreData already gives a unique id to every record, so you don't need to add another one unless you are trying to store external ids.  The relationship will use that internal id, but you don't really see that while using the objects.

Comment: Oh perfect! Thank you for your answers.